# Quick cast with one key only

Tags: dota-2

Is there a way to cast 2  or 3 abilities(spells) in a row with pressing 1 hot key only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that you can configure a Macro. Most of the gaming keyboards have macro keys.

Otherwise you could use [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) and configure one of your keys to make a sequence of keys, with a delay between them.

You have a lot of examples in their forum.

Comment: I was hoping to do this using Game's UI,

Comment: have you used auto key in dota2 does it work?

Comment: I don't know if now works, but i think it does. I stopped playing dota few month ago.

Comment: here you have a example with Invoker: http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/87413-dota-2-invoker-script/

Comment: Yes this is very promising!!